# How do I get the answer from AJAX/PHP?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Let's say I'm sending this simple ajax request (jquery):

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/ajax/requestForm.php',
   data: {'action':'request', 'language':'sk'},
   complete: function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

In my requestForm.php, I have:

```
<?php echo 'Hello answer!'; ?>
```

What alert() shows me in the browser:

> [object Object]

What I want it to show:

> Hello answer!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `complete:` to `success:` and that should give you the desired result.

Complete is a function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified", "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror"). That is why you are getting an object returned.

Answer (score 0):

you want

```
alert(data.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

The response will be available in the responseText or responseXML property of the data object.

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/ajax/requestForm.php',
   data: {'action':'request', 'language':'sk'},
   success: function(data){
      alert(data);
   }
});
```

Success instead of complete, complete is for closing down functionality, like removing spinners etc. @Jorge is right, you should return either xml, JSON, or for output html is sometimes ok for mini-apps, but as I presume you are simply testing jQuery AJAX, what you needed was to use the success property to return the data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should output "structured" data in the php script, like json.
For example:

```
$output = array('message'=>'Hello answer!', 'otherdata'=>'Value of other data');
echo json_encode($output);
```

And in the jQuery you should do:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json', //The type of data you're expecting to receive from the server
   url: '/ajax/requestForm.php',
   data: {'action':'request', 'language':'sk'},
   success: function(response){
      alert(response.message);
   }
});
```

That should produce the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax() complete() first parameter (data) is [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, while success() first parameter (data as well) is request's response data itself.

Using complete():
To access response data from [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) you need to read either `jqXHR.responseText` or `jqXHR.responseXML` property `alert(jqXHR.responseText)`.

Using success():
Simple `alert(data)` will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

you should use `success` instead of `complete`, and try

```
dataType: 'html',
```

**html**: Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

or

```
dataType: 'text',
```

**text**: A plain text string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: and why is that? using dataType changes response object into plain text